# svn, after restore repository from backup, show log does not show new commit unless I check the checkbox in tortoisesvn - include merged revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I had a problem with my svn server so I had to get all the data back from backup.
However the backup was old (a couple of odays ago) and since then I had a few new commits to svn.  that means my local svn had newer revisions than the repository I currently have.
For me that is ok no problem, I will just use the older repository and commit new stuff as if this is my repository (I do clean checkout and work on the main repository).

However something is very strange with show log:
when I do show log (with tortoise svn or command line) then I do not see the changes in log as for my current commits, i see them only if I check the checkbox in tortoise svn called: **Include Merged revisions**

Anyone knows what is happening? what should I do to see all the revisions again in show log as was workin so far?

More info

1. date 8/2/2010 work with svn repository (commit,update,etc)
2. date 8/3/2010 work with svn repository (commit,update,etc)
3. date 8/4/2010 take the svn server replace its hard disk image with svn repository by the one from 8/2/2010
4. 8/4/2010 Continue working with this svn repostory (checkout clean version commit,update,etc).
5. The outcome is that i don't see anything in show log from 8/4/2010 unless i check the checkbox "Include merged revisions"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its a little difficult to understand the exact specific sequence you followed when you hit this problem. Can you re-word and make this more specific?

Comment: added "More info" to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you back your repository on the server to an older state you need to do a clean checkout on the client to get back in sync.

Answer (score 2):

Clear the log cache:
Settings-dialog->saved data->log messages (show log dialog).